# CSS filter not working in Firefox or IE

Tags: html, css, filter, cross-browser

I'm trying to use a CSS filter to blur an image on hover. The image is contained in a button. It works in Opera, Chrome, and Edge. It doesn't work in Firefox or IE. If I put the filter on the button itself it works in all the browsers, but I'd prefer for only the image to blur. Any help would be appreciated. 
CSS

```
button>img:hover {
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

HTML

```
  <button type="button">
    <img src="http://factory38.com/gallery-images/tree_thumb.jpg" width="200" alt="tree">
</button>
```

Demo

https://codepen.io/mrsmith71/pen/wjYoOY

Answer (score 0):

`filter` seems to be at experimental stage and lacks of support for some browsers.

However the cause seems different here, on Firefox where i tested, the image is not considered hovered, it's the button that is, so that this will work (`:hover` is on button instead of image):

```css
button:hover img {
  filter: blur(2px);
}

button{
  width: 300px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #606dbc,
    #606dbc 10px,
    #465298 10px,
    #465298 20px
  );
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
    <img src="http://factory38.com/gallery-images/tree_thumb.jpg" width="200" alt="tree">
</button>
```

**Edit**: tested and works on Firefox, Chrome and Edge

Comment: That's exactly what I found. So at least it isn't just me. I guess my best choice, if I really care about a blur on all browsers is to do it on the button rather than the image.

Comment: actually this should add the blur only to the image, not to the button. But it targets any image in a hovered button, instead of tagetting any hovered image in a button

Comment: @cjsmith edited the button with bigger size and stripes to demonstrate the blur is on the image only

Comment: Doh! I had "button>img:hover" and should have had "button:hover img".
Thanks for straightening me out. Much appreciated